# Adding data to an existing JSON file without overwriting it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

**The idea:**

I want to add a JSON object to an existing JSON file, but not overwrite the existing data in the file.

The `uid-003` object should come subordinate to `uID` after the existing `uid-xxx` entries.

**The problem:**

No solution approach works as it should. The `append()` approach also returns the error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`.

**The current code**

Python code:

```
user = {
    "uid-003": {
        "username": "username-3",
        "pinned": "pinned",
        "created": {
            "date": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "time": "HH:MM:SS"
        },
        "verified": {
            "checked": False
        }
    }
}

with open("path/to/json", "r+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    
    temp = data['uID']
    temp.append(user)

    json.dump(data, file)
```

JSON file:

```json
{
    "uID": {
        "uid-001": {
            "username": "username-1",
            "pinned": false,
            "created": {
                "date": "20-12-2021",
                "time": "21:13:39"
            },
            "verified": {
                "checked": false
            }
        },
        "uid-002": {
            "username": "username-2",
            "pinned": true,
            "created": {
                "date": "20-12-2021",
                "time": "21:13:39"
            },
            "verified": {
                "checked": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add your *user* dictionary to the existing 'uID' key. If you update a file that's been opened with r+ and you're increasing the amount of data in the file, you'll need to seek to the beginning before writing. This should help:

```
import json

THE_FILE = 'the_file.json'

user = {
    "uid-003": {
        "username": "username-3",
        "pinned": "pinned",
        "created": {
            "date": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "time": "HH:MM:SS"
        },
        "verified": {
            "checked": False
        }
    }
}

with open(THE_FILE, 'r+') as jfile:
    j = json.load(jfile)
    for k, v in user.items():
        j['uID'][k] = v
    jfile.seek(0)
    json.dump(j, jfile, indent=4)
```

Note: The iteration over *user.items()* isn't really necessary in this case but serves to show how you might use this pattern when *user* contains more dictionaries than just the one in your example

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
> Blockquote

This is quite explicite, you are trying to append a element in a object as it was a list.

what you need to do is  convert you uID from an obj to as list. It will simplify your life if you need to manipulate this object later

Another way is:

```py
user = {
    "uid-003": {
        "username": "username-3",
        "pinned": "pinned",
        "created": {
            "date": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "time": "HH:MM:SS"
        },
        "verified": {
            "checked": False
        }
    }
}

with open("path/to/json", "r+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    keys = user.keys()
    data['uID'][keys[0]] = user[0]

    json.dump(data, file)
```

Answer (score -1):

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

You can use [dict update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20update#dict.update)

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'r+') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data['uID'].update(user)
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```